# Install4j - Is it possible to run TSQL queries?

Tags: install4j

When working with Server-Sql, sometimes it needs to use Transact-SQL queries. Is it possible to execute it through Install4j?

**EDIT**

I'm using the Server SQL JDBC driver: - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.

When I'm trying to execute the following script in the SSMS it works without any problem:

`USE [${installer:DbName}]
GO
CREATE USER [Guest] FOR LOGIN [Guest]
GO
USE [${installer:acDbName}]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [Guest]
GO`

, but when executing it with the "Execute SQL script" I get the following error: `com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.jdbc.ExecuteSqlScriptAction [ID 8123]: Error executing script line "U", error message: "Could not find stored procedure 'U'."`

When enabling the *statement delimeter* with ; I'm getting the next error:

```
"Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."
```

Comment: `GO` is not a T-SQL statement; it's a batch separator that works only in Management Studio (or `sqlcmd`). Fortunately in your case the `GO` statements are unnecessary since these statements will all fit in one batch. Try removing them. (Delimiting the individual statements with `;` should be optional, but it depends on how the text is being parsed and processed by `ExecuteSqlScriptAction`.)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the JDBC driver that you are using can handle TSQL or not, install4j does not have support for specific databases.

Comment: The JDBC driver I'm using does handle TSQL. so in that case using it with _SQL action_ script?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still won't work. I've edited my question.